# scrolling div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div that's currently scrolling using the `overflow: auto` and a set height in CSS. I have a button and want to click and make the div scroll up slightly. I've tried using animate and scrollTop and neither have worked.

How can I do this?

Comment: look, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/pVY2m/ (Just found this sample on the web)

Comment: can u post what u have tried out

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript/jQuery will allow you to gradually scroll a div with `overflow:auto` on it:

```
// The <div> with (overflow:auto)
var scrollBox = $("#leDiv");

// height of the scrollable area
var boxHeight = scrollBox.height();

// height of the scrollable content
var contentHeight = scrollBox[0].scrollHeight;

$('#scrollButton').click(function() {

    // Get the current position of the scroll
    var currentPos = scrollBox.scrollTop();

    // Dont scroll if were at the top    
    if (currentPos <= 0) {
        currentPos = 0;
    } else {
        scrollBox.animate({
            scrollTop: currentPos - 80
        }, 600);
    }
});​
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/B5sR9/4/